# How to get dependency version from Scala Play! framework build file

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies

I'm using Play! framework to build my application. I have such dependency:

`"com.coolDependency" % "superLib" % "0.3.89"`

Somewhere in the code, I'd like to get the version of the superLib. But is it possible to do with Play! tools? My code is dependent from the version of superLib. For example:

`val coolVal = "importantThingsHere - 0.3.89"`

As the version of superLib is changing quite often, I don't like to change the version of it in the build file and in the code. 
I could put it in the configuration file and read it from there both in build file and in the code, as well as parse the build.scala file in the code and get the version by extracting it from the build file.

Is there any prettier way of doing this? I was trying to play around with play.api.Play, but didn't succeeded.

Currently, I decided to get maven property file from classloader.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone will try to do something similar:

`val properties = new Properties
properties.load(Play.application.resourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/com.coolDependency/superLib/pom.properties").get)
properties.get("version")`